# ubuntu "you have held broken packages"

Tags: unix, ubuntu, terminal

(using ubuntu 14.04.3)
i need to install libx32gcc-4.8-dev libc6-dev-i386.
when i try to download it by writing:

`sudo apt-get install libx32gcc-4.8-dev libc6-dev-i386`

the terminal returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libx32gcc-4.8-dev : Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) but it         is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libx32gcc1 (>= 1:4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) but it is     not going to be installed
                 Depends: lib32asan0 (>= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libx32asan0 (>= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
```

and it doesn't work.
i have tried

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libx32gcc-4.8-dev libc6-dev-i386
```

same result
and

```
sudo apt-get remove libx32gcc-4.8-dev libc6-dev-i386
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libx32gcc-4.8-dev libc6-dev-i386
```

but it doesn't work either...

Comment: This question belongs to [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to fix the packages by doing this 
sudo apt-get install -f